# Why is JQuery .html() returning null?

Tags: jquery, html, qunit

I have a QUnit test suite and am calling

```
 $('#idForElement').html();
```

inside a QUnit test (which is registered on `$(document).ready()`, and then run), but this function returns `null` in Chrome, Firefox and IE.

*However*, in the script tab of Firebug in Firefox, I am able to get the expected string by adding the code as a watch expression and can see a HTML element displayed on the page and in the HTML tab of Firebug.

I've read http://api.jquery.com/html/, I have assigned this into new `var`, an initalised string, put the result of `$('#idForElement');` into a variable and called `.html()` on that, tried alerts in those browsers.

What's the next step to get this working?

Comment: Did you verify that `var foo = $("#idForElement");` was indeed pulling the DOM node you were looking for?  Keep in mind that `.html()` pulls in the innerHtml of an element, so if the node contains nothing, you'll get nothing.

Comment: I did, yes as I was `.append`ing to `foo` successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rookie error.

Was calling `$('#idForElement')`, but setting the var to $('idForElement').

It turns out you can append to an empty wrapped set.

Answer (score 4):

It may depend on when you are calling this function. If you do this before the [document.ready](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29) event, the element may not exist yet. Try wrapping your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //your code goes here
});
```

Comment: It's inside a QUnit test which are registered inside a ready block, then called, so it's not that.